# How can I check in Spring-DSL if Camel is shutting down?

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I have a route that contains a wiretap element that redirects to a route that tries to make a bean invocation after a certain delay (approximately 20 seconds). However when the application shuts down, I get errors because the bean doesn't exist anymore and during shutdown it cannot be created. I want to make my application shutdown gracefully by checking the state of the application after the delay. How can I do that?

```
<route id="triggerAfterDelay">
    ...
    <delay><constant>20000</constant></delay>

    <!-- TODO Check if we're not shutting down. -->

    <bean ref="myBean" method="updateAfterDelay"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently I have a working solution by using the following filter. However I'm still interested in **"native" camel ways** to do this.

```
public class CamelFilter implements ApplicationContextAware {
    public boolean isMyBeanNotAvailable() {
        boolean notAvailable = false;
        try {
            notAvailable = this.applicationContext.getBean("myBean") == null;
        } catch (BeanCreationNotAllowedException bcnae) {
            notAvailable = true;
        }
        return notAvailable;
    }
}
```

With the following route:

```
<route id="triggerAfterDelay">
    ...
    <delay><constant>20000</constant></delay>

    <filter>
        <method ref="camelFilter" method="isMyBeanNotAvailable"/>
        <stop/>
    </filter>

    <bean ref="myBean" method="updateAfterDelay"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Camel 2.11.x or newer, you might be able to do that with the new [ControlBus](https://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html) component.

Maybe easier and also available in earlier Camel versions is to subclass `org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport`. If myBean extends `ServiceSupport` you have to implement the `doStop()` method. There you can set a flag (`AtomicBoolean`?) to signify that shutdown is on progress. In `updateAfterDelay()` you can check that flag.

Comment: I checked out the ControlBus component you mentioned. I queried for the status of the "triggerAfterDelay" route, but at the moment of the error, the status is still Started.

Comment: The second suggestion is a bit tricky, because I use a Camel Proxy as a bean in the current situation. At the moment I don't see/know how to incorporate your second suggestion in this proxy.